# Import "taggit.managers" could not be resolved

Tags: python, django, backend, django-taggit

Im currently learning django with the book "Django 2" by Antonio Melé.
I got an error when I import "from taggit.managers import TaggableManager".
I already install django-taggit and django-extensions. I also already added 'taggit' to INSTALLED_APPS.
Here is my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
'taggit'
]
```

My models.py (There are more classes but I put the one that im working on):

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Post (models.Model):
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('draft', 'Draft'),
    ('published', 'Published'),
)

title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')

author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')

body = models.TextField()

publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='published')

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-publish',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

objects = models.Manager()
published = PublishedManager()

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=[self.publish.year, self.publish.month, self.publish.day, self.slug])

tags = TaggableManager()
```

[Image of the error, just in case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gigsf.png)

I ran python manage.py shell and after the following:

```
from blog.models import Post
post = Post.objects.get(id=1)
post.tag.add('post1', 'blogpost', 'tag1')
post.tags.all()
```

And the tags were added successfuly.

Comment: This is a list formatting issue: remove the trailing comma and close the square bracket.

Comment: I edited the post, in my code i did close the square bracket, when i made the post i forgot to close it in the question editor. The error its still there. Thanks for the response btw.

Comment: From the image of the error you posted it seems it's just your IDE that fails to detect the taggit library and so it creates a warning. I'd make sure the libraries in your IDE are reindexed and/or the virtual environment is correctly configured for your project. Your code just works, what you ran in the shell proves it.

Comment: @Marco Thanks for the response! I'm really new, how can I make sure the libraries are reindexed?
Also, I'm using venv and I have a requirements.txt with all the dependencies, but is there any way to know if my venv is correctly configured?
As I said I'm learning from the book and the django documentation, I tried to search how to solve this problem and i found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your indentation in the models.py is the issue

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33524474)

Answer (score 0):

Restart your python server then run the initial migration

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I know it is 11 months, but I had the same problem and I know how to fix it.
You need to add extra path for analysis in vscode settings.
[look at this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmq2X.png)